# How to call a JS function after angular element is rendered in page?

Tags: angularjs

I have the following div:

```
<div style="font-size:15px;"  class="title">
    <div>{{specialOffer.Name}}</div>
</div>
```

I need to execute a JS function after {{specialOffer.Name}} is replaced with its value. Sorry, I'm an Angular newbie, trying to solve some bugs on an existing code.

I tried $(document).ready or window.onload, but these events get fired too quickly.

Answer (score 2):

**You can do that this way:** Its one possibility and It is good to be inside directives while talking about rendering.

```js
angular.module('myApp',[])
.directive('afterRender', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      cb: '&'
    },
    link: function($scope, element, attrs) {
       var watch = $scope.$watch(function() {

      }, function() {
        // Runs after rendered
        $scope.$evalAsync(function() {
          $scope.cb();
        });
      });
    },
  };
})  
.controller('myCtrl',function($scope){
            
  $scope.specialOffer = {Name:"Woops!"}
  $scope.callMeAfterRender = function(){
     alert('Hey I am called :)');
  } 
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.10/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller='myCtrl'>
<span after-render 
      cb='callMeAfterRender()'>{{specialOffer.Name}}</span>
</div>
```

Happy Helping!

Comment: Thanks for you comment. I tried this, but when my function is called, the div is empty and looks like this: <div after-render="" cb="fitSpecialOfferTagText()" class="ng-isolate-scope ng-binding">
                            
                        </div>

Comment: are you sure your two way binding is working ? {{specialOffer.Name}} is not empty ? the solution code i have given you is working all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Try using ng-init, see this

```
<div style="font-size:15px;"  class="title">
    <div ng-init="functionName(specialOffer.Name)">
       {{specialOffer.Name}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it.

```
$scope.$watch('specialOffer.Name', function(newVal, oldVal) {
  callYourFunction()
});
```

Every time `specialOffer.Name` changes, the callback is ran and the DOM is updated (meaning `{{specialOffer.Name}}` gets "filled in").

---

But this has a "code smell" to it. I can't be sure that it's a bad approach without knowing the context, but I'm pessimistic. Check out [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_04) to get a better understanding of how data binding works.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution.Plese find the same.
Here the problem was solved by using angularjs directive post link.

```
app.directive('afterRender', function () {
return {
    link: {
        post: function ($scope, elem, attr) {             
               $timeout(function () {
                  alert('Data was rendered'); 
               //  add your java script code               
              }, 0);
          }  
      }            
    };
});






<div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller='myCtrl'>
    <span after-render>{{expression}}</span>
</div>
```